# Module written as direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra, direct-sum

I'm taking Non Commutative Algebra course and today my professor left the following exercise: if $R$ is a ring and $M$ is an $R$-module writtem as
$$M = \sum_{i=1}^{n} V_i,$$
where each $V_i$ is an irreducible module (there are not non trivial submodules), then
$$M = \bigoplus_{s=1}^{k}V_{i_s}.$$
How can I prove it?

After this exercise, he suggest us this result: if $R$ is an unital ring such that
$$A=\bigoplus_i V_i,$$
where each $V_i$ is an irreducible module and the sum is not necessarily finite, then
$$A = \bigoplus_{s=1}^{k}V_{i_s}.$$

To prove the last one, I use the fact that $1 \in R$ and then, there are $i_1, \dots, i_k$ such that
$$1 = e_{i_1} + \dots + e_{i_s},$$
where $e_{i_j}\in V_{i_j}$. Then, for $r \in R$,
$$r = 1r = e_{i_1}r + \dots + e_{i_s}r.$$
Since $V_{i_j}$ is an $R$-module, then $e_{i_j}r\in V_{i_j}$. This implies that $r \in \bigoplus_{s=1}^{k}V_{i_s}$, and that $A = \bigoplus_{s=1}^{k}V_{i_s}$ as we wanted. Is this proof correct? **Can I use this kind of idea to prove the first exercise?**

Comment: The first question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294947/a-module-which-is-a-sum-of-a-family-of-minimal-submodules-is-a-direct-sum-of-a-s?rq=1) (actually I think there are better links) and the second question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2046872/29335).  To answer your final question, no, the reasoning for proving the second one (showing the sum is finite) does not seem to have anything relevant for the other task (showing that such a sum can be refined to a direct sum.)